# PHP Regular Expression to Match Function Name and Parameters with string like Needle(needle|needle)

Tags: php, regex

I am filtering database results with a query string that looks like this:

attribute=operator(value|optional value)

I'll use

```
$_GET['attribute'];
```

to get the value.

I believe the right approach is using regex to get matches on the rest.

The preferred output would be

```
print_r($matches);
array(
    1 => operator
    2 => value
    3 => optional value
)
```

The operator will always be one word and consist of letters: like(), between(), in().

The values can be many different things including letters, numbers, spaces commas, quotation marks, etc...

I was asked where my code was failing and didn't include much code because of how poorly it worked.  Based on the accepted answer, I was able to whip up a regex that *almost* works.

EDIT 1

```
$pattern = "^([^\|(]+)\(([^\|()]+)(\|*)([^\|()]*)";
```

Edit 2

```
$pattern = "^([^\|(]+)\(([^\|()]+)(\|*)([^\|()]*)"; // I thought this would work.
```

Edit 3

```
$pattern = "^([^\|(]+)\(([^\|()]+)(\|+)?([^\|()]+)?"; // this does work!
```

Edit 4

```
$pattern = "^([^\|(]+)\(([^\|()]+)(?:\|)?([^\|()]+)?"; // this gets rid of the middle matching group.
```

The only remaining problem is when the 2nd optional parameter does not exist, there is still an empty $matches array.

Comment: Where is your code failing?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @AndyLester think I can get your .02 to wrap up this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script, with the input "operator(value|optional value)", returns the array you expect:

```
<?php
    $attribute = $_GET['attribute'];
    $result = preg_match("/^([\w ]+)\(([\w ]+)\|([\w ]*)\)$/", $attribute, $matches);

    print($matches[1] . "\n");
    print($matches[2] . "\n");
    print($matches[3] . "\n");
?>
```

This assumes your "values" match `[\w ]` regexp (all word characters plus space), and that the `|` you specify is a literal `|`...

Comment: @Andy Lester: sorry, I didn't read your comment, you are right... :-)

Comment: Ah, I see, "values" has to be [\w] in your answer.  I need basically anything but a | so "/^([^\|;]+)\(([^\|;]+)\|([^\|;]*)\)$/" works for me.  However, the last one still isn't an optional match and I'm having the most trouble with that.

Comment: I understand, I put optional value but didn't make the separator optional.  It works as you did it.